# implement MOSCAP in an FPGA (or another digital IC)

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, fpga

Can I implement MOSCAP in an FPGA? I mean can I connect drain and source of a transistor to gnd and gate to another node? It can be another device other than FPGA. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have control over connections at the transistor level when using an FPGA. You need to draw your own layout for the MOSCAP and build it as a full-custom IC. I hope you have lots of money for this.